# Reinstalling mysql on centos giving conflicts

Tags: centos, mysql

I am trying to reinstall mysql on centos.
There is no package installed related to mysql based on

```
yum list installed|grep -i mysql
```

But when I install

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

I am getting conflicts

```
Transaction check error:


file /etc/my.cnf conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys conflicts between attempted installs of mysql55w-libs-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64 and mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/my_print_defaults conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqladmin conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqldump conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlimport conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlshow conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlslap conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz conflicts between attempted installs of mariadb-1:5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 and mysql55w-5.5.46-1.w6.x86_64
```

Comment: Good to know.  Did you have a question?

Comment: I solved it , but the question was how to get rid of the conflicts

Comment: This issue is a few months old but as I had encountered the same kind of issue and landed on this page. So, I'd like to add an answer, which is there and enclosing this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756308/problems-installing-mariadb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have mariadb installed, which is a fork of mysql so retains a lot of similarities.

Try

```
yum list installed | grep -i maria
```

Comment: still no list of installed packages

Comment: You could install yum-utils and use repoquery with the 'file' command.

repoquery --file /usr/bin/mysql

That will show you what package the file belongs to